# How to use cursor correctly?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a script like this:

```
declare @username nvarchar(255)
declare @Alterstatement nvarchar(2000)
declare @userloginname nvarchar(255)
declare @InsertIntoHistory nvarchar(2000)

declare getusername cursor
for 
    select name from [SysAdmin].[dbo].[DisabledAccount]
      where name in (select name from sys.server_principals)

open getusername
Fetch next from getusername into @username

while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
begin 
    set @userloginname = '[' + @username + ']'`

    set @Alterstatement = 'Alter Login' +@userloginname +'Disable'
    set @InsertIntoHistory = 'Insert into DisabledAccountHistory (DisabledName,ServerName) values(''' 
        + @username + ''','''+ @@servername +''')'
    exec(@alterstatement)
    exec(@InsertIntoHistory)
    Fetch next from getusername
    into @username
end

close getusername
deallocate getusername
```

I'm using this script to disable some users and insert into a history table. But when I run this, some problem shows up. For example when I have only one user that I need to disable, it will run 3 times and insert 3 rows into the history table. How can I ask it just run 1 time for each user?

Comment: `select distinct name` to ensure you only get 1 row for each user?

Comment: no cuz the problem is the cursor runs for 3 times, it is only taking one name from the sys table. @AlexK.

Comment: If this is executing three times it is because there are three rows in [SysAdmin].[dbo].[DisabledAccount] for a given user. You also should use QUOTENAME instead of trying to wrap [] around your values. Using quotename handles all the edge cases correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would get rid of the cursor completely as it isn't needed here. You can still disable all the logins and insert the data into your history table.

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = ''

select @SQL = @SQL + 'ALTER LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ' DISABLE;'
from [SysAdmin].[dbo].[DisabledAccount]
where name in (select name from sys.server_principals)
group by name

exec sp_executesql @SQL

Insert into DisabledAccountHistory 
(
    DisabledName
    , ServerName
) 
select name
    , @@servername 
from [SysAdmin].[dbo].[DisabledAccount]
where name in (select name from sys.server_principals)
group by name
```